migrate legacy java system transaction into spring
I try to find the optimal solution for the following:
I have an old JAVA based monolit legacy system, which communicates with servlets.
I would like to migrate this using spring framework.
I have the REST Controllers, however I have one problem:
the system has a unique DB connection handling (it uses CORBA and has some interceptors), which works the following: when the user logs in, there is a DB session assiated with the user session, and it is not commited until there is an explicit save command. For each call, there is an interceptor, which sets the connection in lower level of application.
I know it is totally opposit with REST, however I have to keep this logic :(
If I want to have the minimum impact( and dont want to rewrite ) I am thinking about the following: I introduce a OncePerRequestFilter which intercepts each calls, which does this DB Connection settings for the lower layers of this application.
Is this a good solution?
A have another solution, which does not look good for me: using aspect orient programming, and make this pre/post interception of the REST methods.
Another thing: I need some Interceptor as well after the Rest operation is finished.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

If each user session is associated with a DB session, why not use a session scoped bean? You can then inject instances of the bean, and Spring will make sure you get the correct instance.

Yes, it helps , but my main challenge is to use a proxy before and after each Rest operation call.
